# C IPC: Revoke access to shared memory, similar to Microsoft/Apple Clipboard

Tags: c, windows, ipc, clipboard, shared-memory

As I understand it, the way you interact with the clipboard in Windows(And MacOS too, I think) is similar to:

1. Open the clipboard (Requesting access)
2. Clear the clipboard
3. Allocate new Global Memory, and get a pointer to that memory
4. Fill the memory
5. Release the memory handle
6. Indicate to the system that the clipboard is ready.

Those final steps are what I am concerned with- Reading up on shared memory APIs, I see no way for a provider of shared memory to enforce/verify that someone it has shared the memory with has in fact released it. Without such a guarantee, the "Copier" could manipulate the data freely even when it was supposed to be "Done",  without the knowledge of the clipboard owner.

Can someone help me find how one process can create shared memory (Similar to shm_open()), share that memory, and then know when the client they shared to has completely released that memory (Or force revoke it- either works)?

Alternatively, am I either having a key misunderstanding in how these clipboards work, or are these OS taking further special OS level action that a normal program can not replicate?

Comment: 1. There's less connection between shared memory and clipboards than you think.  2. If you don't want other clients to manipulate the data, why are you allowing them write access?  If you only permit others to open the shared memory for read, they can't corrupt your data, and if they fail to synchronize and read one of your half-completed writes, that's their problem not yours.

Comment: 1. If you do know, could you clarify how clipboards otherwise work? I realize they could b e copying it out of the shared memory buffer (or similar structure) into a new one, but that seems inefficient.

2. Its similar to the clipboard case. I want to allow something to write into the shared memory for a bit, but once it's done I want it to no longer access it, unless I later re-grant the access. I also do want (At least sometimes) the clients to have write access, similar to clipboards

Comment: The Windows clipboard gets its efficiency from lazy evaluation.  Although the sequence you describe is allowed, it's not the best.  Windows uses COM (OLE Automation) to enable "Give the system a list of known formats and a function pointer but no actual data".  Then when someone reads the clipboard, your function is called with the requested format and you prepare the data in just that one particular format, not all the formats you support.  And if no one pastes before the clipboard content is replaced, no need to ever process the data.  So it's more like a remote procedure call than memory.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for something like a mailslot or a publish/subscriber system?

Comment: W.r.t. clipboard, I know about the format half of things, though that route can not outlive the copying application's close(With some exceptions, but those are outside the scope I am concerned with). I am concerned with when I have no guarantee that the app we allow some write access will be around for future requests.

I actually have a system working for what I want with pipes, but I am trying to see if I can get the maximum efficiency that sharedmem allows without compromising security, even in edge cases.  For pipes, I use an arbiter service and "splice" calls, which has an extra copy.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the answer, please let me know this makes sense here, I won't be able to try it for a couple of days:

In the man page for [fcntl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) it mentions the following behavior: `EBUSY  cmd is F_ADD_SEALS, arg includes F_SEAL_WRITE, and there exists a writable, shared mapping on the file referred to by fd`

So you could create a block of shared memory, pass it to a trusted arbiter, and not trust that block until you successfully apply F_SEAL_WRITE (Thus knowing the client has released all open writable mappings, and is unable to create any more)

I was looking for this for most of this week, but found the answer almost right after posting to stackoverflow. If I got this right, sorry for the trouble but hopefully it helps people in the future!

Comment: Do note however that, at least on Windows, "Memory mapped files are not supported with byte range locks."   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/locking-and-unlocking-byte-ranges-in-files